# Animating and rotating pages using JQuery,

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate, slideshow, settimeout

I'm creating a sliding/animating pages template for a website.

By default, I'm displaying 3 pages on the user screen.
On the left, we are able to see 10% of the previous page.
In the center of the screen, I'm displaying the current page and on the right, we are able to see 10% of the next page.

In this website, there is a top menu allowing us to choose any item and navigate between pages. Each item is linked to one of the 5 current pages of this website and it display the according title of the page.

When I'm clicking on one item of the top menu, I'm sliding/animating to the left or right the pages until I set up and reach the correct page linked to the selected menu item.

Here is the "myLoopright" function where I can call many times the sliddingright function.

```
        function myLoopright () 
        {          
            //  create a loop function
            setTimeout(function () 
            {   
                sliddingright(page_id_target_right,previous_right_old,previous_right,next_right,pages_numbers,loop);
                loopcount++;    //  increment the counter

                if (loopcount <= (difference_pages-1)) 
                {   
                   myLoopright();       //  ..  again which will trigger another 
                }                        
            }, 1100) //  ..  setTimeout()
        } // closing myLoop function
```

And here is the sliding right function

```
function sliddingright(page_id_target_right,previous_right_old,previous_right,next_right,pages_numbers,loop)
{

        duration=1000;
        //Update top Menu DOM items
        $('ul#navigation #'+page_id_target_right).addClass('active');
        $('ul#navigation #'+next_right).addClass('next');
        $('ul#navigation #'+pages_numbers).addClass('previous');

         //Update DOM pages                     
            previous_right_old=parseInt(pages_numbers-1);           
            // PREVIOUS TO HIDDEN
            $('#content .'+previous_right_old).css({ 'left' : '-73%','background-color' : '#EAEAEA'}).animate({'left' : '-151%'}, duration, easing, function(){$('#content .'+previous_right_old).addClass('hidden')});
            // ACTIVE TO PREVIOUS           
            $('#content .'+pages_numbers).css({ 'margin' : '0 6%', 'left' : '5%', 'right' : '5%'}).animate({'left' : '-73%', 'margin-right' : '0%', 'margin-left' : '0%', 'backgroundColor' : '#EFF0F1' }, duration, easing, function(){$('#content .'+pages_numbers).removeClass('hidden').addClass('previous')});                     
            // NEXT TO ACTIVE           
            $('#content .'+page_id_target_right).css({ 'left' : '95%','background-color' : '#EAEAEA'}).animate({'left' : '5%', 'margin-right' : '6%', 'margin-left' : '6%', 'backgroundColor' : '#FFFFFF' }, duration, easing, function(){$('#content .'+page_id_target_right).addClass('active').removeClass('hidden');});
            // HIDDEN TO NEXT
            $('#content .'+next_right).removeClass('hidden').addClass('next').appendTo('#content').css({ 'left' : '173%', 'backgroundColor' : '#EFF0F1'}).animate({'left' : '95%'}, duration);
    }
```

This code is working, but, when I have to slide many pages, the sliding effect isn't fluent.

So I would like to call the "myLoopright" function when all the animations of the the sliddingright function are done and delete the setTimeout function.

To see my developing code, you can go here:
http://jsfiddle.net/K2xZB/89/

Cheers

Comment: This might be a good question over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.